# I have curl documentation for how to use a site's APIs but would like to use Node JS for the API

Tags: node.js, curl

I'm trying to make an API for saleforeceIQ and their documentation doesn't include Node JS which is what I'm most familiar with. I'm wondering if I could make an API with Node JS from looking at their documentation. Here is their curl documentation get get an account:

```
DEFINITION
GET https://api.salesforceiq.com/v2/accounts/{accountId}

REQUEST
curl 'https://api.salesforceiq.com/v2/accounts/abcdef1234567890abcdef0b'
    -X GET
    -u [API Key]:[API Secret]
    -H 'Accept: application/json'

RESPONSE
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
{
    "id" : "abcdef1234567890abcdef0b",
    "modifiedDate" : 1389124003573,
    "name" : "Account"
}
```

Here is what I have come up with so far for converting this to Node JS:

```
var key = "[KEY]"
var secret = "[SECRET]"

var request = require('request');

var headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://api.salesforceiq.com/v2/accounts/',
    headers: headers
};

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("body " +body);
    }
    else{
        console.log(error)
    }
}

request(options, callback)
```

My problem is I don't know how to incorporate the key and secret into Node JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The -u option of curl specify the username and password. So translated for request.js became:

```
var options = {
  // your options
  'auth': {
    'user': '[KEY]',
    'pass': '[SECRET]',
    'sendImmediately': true
  }
}
```

You can find more info here: https://github.com/request/request#http-authentication

Comment: Got this to work after I switch 'sendImmediately' to true. Thank you very much.